# Why is it thought of 'T *name' to be the C way and 'T* name' to be the C++ way?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, history, conventions

Note: This question is about the position of the asterisk (`*`).

In most C code I see (e.g., in [Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)), all variable declarations / definitions use the `T *name` format, i.e., bind the `*` to the variable name. The pointer is thought of belonging to the variable, not the type.

In most C++ code I see, the format is `T* name`, i.e., it binds the `*` to the type of the variable . The pointer is thought of belonging to the type, not the variable. I myself, as a pure C++ coder, also use this format, as a *pointer-to-type* clearly (for me) belongs to the type, not the variable. (Incidently, even the C++ standard uses this format in the examples. :) )

Is there a (historic) reason for this? Has the way of thinking just changed when programmers started doing C++?

It would also be nice if a C coder (that uses the former format) could explain on why s/he uses it, and not the latter.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you write "pointer to function returning `T`"?  Just asking.

Comment: i think `int *a, *b` vs `int* a, b` is the reason some prefer former

Comment: @Nemo: `std::identity<T (*)()>::type pf;`. :P Of course `typedef T (*pf_type)(); pf_type pf;`, but that's only because of the parsing rules.

Comment: @Anycorn: I don't buy that argument -- nobody writes code like your second example. That's just as bad as the "always add braces to IF statements because we're assuming the next guy is too dumb to add them " argument.

Comment: @billy I'm puzzled why you tell Anycorn his point is a non-issue, when you make exactly the same point as him in your answer!

Comment: I was tempted to close it as not constructive myself. :-)

Comment: @Bill I'm saying I disagree with those people, not that that isn't the reason things are done that way.

Comment: Am I the only one putting a space both before and after the `*` so that pointer uses are blindingly obvious in my code?

Comment: @Xeo: I don't think `std::identity` really made it into C++0x :(

Comment: @Luc: Doesn't that look more like multiplication? ;)

Comment: @Fred Overflow: I rarely do multiplication at the beginning of a line, without affecting the result :) !

Comment: I bet, Pascal background people (including me) always use int* a style :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace).

> A "typical C programmer" writes `int *p;` and explains it "`*p` is what is the `int`" emphasizing syntax, and may point to the C (and C++) declaration grammar to argue for the correctness of the style. Indeed, the `*` binds to the name `p` in the grammar.
>
> A "typical C++ programmer" writes `int* p;` and explains it "`p` is a pointer to an `int`" emphasizing type. Indeed the type of `p` is `int*`. I clearly prefer that emphasis and see it as important for using the more advanced parts of C++ well.

Comment: I will agree that this is a marginally better answer than mine, though it says approximately the same thing with a more subtly expressed opinion bias (but at least it's a famous person's opinion bias, and I guess that counts somehow). But I will say I wasn't aware of this Stroustrup quote when I wrote my answer. So it's amusing that we both said basically the same thing.

Comment: I like this answer because you don't try to justify it with your own opinion. You appeal instead to someone who is more or less an authority on the subject.

Answer (score 23):

If I were to hazard a guess, I would say it's because C++ people are more likely to consider type information to be a thing in and of itself because templates make it possible to manipulate types programatically at compile time. They are also much less likely to declare several variables in the same declaration.

The `T*` style focuses the type information in one place and makes it stand out, and the confusion that would be introduced by something like `T* foo, bar;` with this syntax is a non-issue if you never declare two variables in the same statement.

Personally, I find the `T*` style to be really obnoxious and dislike it immensely. The `*` is part of the type information, it's true, but the way the compiler parses it makes it actually attached to the name, not the type. I think the `T*` way obscures something important that's happening.

In my observations, it seems like I'm a rarity in the C++ community. I've noticed the same thing you have about what style is the most popular.

To be clear, of course, either style works in either language. But I do notice the same thing you do, that one style tends to be a bit more common with C code, and the other a bit more common with C++.

Comment: +1 The `T*` really intends to qualify the *type* and not the *variable*. To avoid the confusion of `T* foo, bar;` I declare them separately.

Comment: @Cicada: I almost always declare them separately too, but still use `T *foo;`.

Comment: If you're thinking code is "obnoxious" over the placement of the asterisk, then I think you're worrying about the wrong things.

Comment: Declaring several variables on the same line makes the code harder to read, whether they are pointers or not. Don't do this: you really don't have to save the HD space where your source code is saved like they had to in the 70s. If that's the only reason why people put the * next to the variable name, it is a really poor one.

Comment: Put it on the right where it belongs and there'd never be any confusion. And declarations wouldn't look stupid either.

Comment: When using templates the types become more important. `MyClass<T>` and `MyClass<T*>` are quite different.

Comment: "The * is part of the type information, it's true, but the way the compiler parses it makes it actually attached to the name, not the type. I think the T* way obscures something important that's happening." You don't need to worry about the compiler. The compiler will be ok. [Optimise your code style for humans, not for the compiler](http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/). Still, +1 from me for a great answer which covers the heart of the _actual_ question well (despite your brief tangent into personal opinion :P)

Comment: @Matt: Put it on the right where it belongs and suddenly language newcomers are _completely_ and _horrendously_ confused, due to the triple meaning of the `*` operator. Just because you and I know the language well enough for it not to confuse us doesn't mean that's the case for everybody.

Comment: @Tomalak: And that's exactly why I think the space belongs there. Not having it there implies something that's not true about how the compiler is seeing the declaration. It leads to humans making mistakes because the visual flow of the statement is at odds with its meaning.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I disagree; you're right that the visual appearance of the statement is at odds with the way the compiler will parse the statement internally, but I don't think that affects the semantic meaning in any way. Indeed, the type of the pointer *is* `T*`. That said, you can make either argument by picking a layer of the compilation process and making a case on its merit.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I'm with @Omnifarious here: Write it the way it's being used, not the way you think it's being used. There's a subtle difference. Allowing 2 ways to do everything is far more confusing to noobs than having them write code that's actually interpreted the way they enter it.

Comment: @Matt: But that's just it. That the grammar binds the `*` to the name not the underlying type isn't really relevant. The type is `T*`; it absolutely _is_ being interpreted in that way on every other level.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: And then someone sees `T*` and wonders what the heck is wrong when `T* foo, bar;` doesn't work. The code author has deliberately mislead people as to how the grammar functions. Every time I see it, I feel like I'm seeing something like `return(x);` (but worse, since that's at least harmless).

Comment: @Omnifarious: That people keep bringing up that corner case so religiously is almost insulting. `T *foo` hides from language newcomers that `*` means different things in different places, which is _far_ more harmful.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Maybe they keep on bringing it up because the point is important. I'm not going to change my answer in response to your comments, and you aren't going to change my mind with them either. I wish C++ had a declarator syntax that was more sensical, but that isn't going to happen. And frankly, I get confused by `T* foo, bar;`, whereas I'm never confused about whether `*` is part of a type name, the pointer dereference operator, or multiplication.

Comment: @Omnifarious: You're not, no. But I don't really care about you - as someone who knows the language anyway, you can do what you like; I care about the thousands of people coming into the language very month who, in just a few years, will be writing software that I have to use in my life. Let's help them out a bit.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Yes, exactly, by encouraging them to use a declarator syntax that reflects the underlying reality of what's happening rather than a cozy fantasy world that will bite them as soon as they leave its constraints.

Comment: @Omnifarious: The underlying reality of what's happening on the level of the grammar. No other level. A pointer has a type, and that type is `T*`; coming at it from the other side, why lie about _that_?

Comment: @Tamalak Geret'kal: But you're not lying to them about that. Forcing someone to come to grips with C++ declarator syntax earlier rather than later is doing them a favor. They will encounter its oddities eventually regardless.

Answer (score 14):

Personally, I would disagree with this -- I don't think there is a C or C++ way of doing this. I've never seen any evidence to suggest that. However, I do have a hypothesis as to why the syntax with the asterisk closer to the declared variable name in C.

In C (at least, in C89, the vast majority of C in use), you must declare all your variables at the top of a block. This leads to programmers doing

```
T a, b, c;
```

relatively often, while in C++ this is rare. (In C++ you declare variables close to where they are used, and variables often have constructor parameters, etc; therefore it's rare to declare multiple objects on a single line)

This also happens to be the only case where the syntax matters, because the statement

```
T* a, b, c;
```

declares one pointer, rather than the three the programmer might expect.

Since putting more than one declaration on a single line is more common in C, and also is the only case where the position of the asterisk matters, it's more likely for the programmer to associate the asterisk with the variable.

That said, I've never seen any evidence of this -- this is just conjecture.

Comment: From experience, I have seen a clear difference between C and C++ sources. For example, I have *never* seen the `T* var` in a C code. And most of the C++ I've read used the `T* var` style rather than `T *var`.

Comment: @Cicada: I see lots of both in both languages.

Answer (score 12):

A couple of people mentioned very good points. I just want to note that while C has kept the meaning "declaration reflects use" very strongly, C++ didn't. Several declarators in C++ don't reflect the use in declarations;

```
int &ref; // but "&ref" has type "int*", not "int".
int &&ref; // but "&&ref" is not valid at all.
```

I don't think that C++ programmers writing it different actually have that as their reason, but it may be something stopping C++ book writers from mentioning it, which may influence those C++ programmers.

Comment: Isn't `&&ref` valid in C++11?

Answer (score 9):

The reason why C programmers tend to use one style while C++ programmers use the other style is quite simple: Kernighan & Ritchie used the "C style" in [their book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_c_programming_language), while Stroustrup used the "C++ style" in [*his* book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C++_Programming_Language).

Comment: This. Also, Stroustrup specifically describes one as more C-like and the other as more C++-like, and why he thinks that is, [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#whitespace)

Answer (score 6):

In K&R they use the `type *name` notation, so may be that's where many C programmers got it.

Answer (score 5):

Because Bjarne had the benefit of hindsight: he realized that the C declarator syntax was "an experiment that failed" (read: the C declarator syntax is retarded). The rest has already been answered by others.

Comment: @Tomalak: Sure, backward compatibility :(

Comment: It would be nice if that `auto name -> type` from functions could catch over to variables, making it less ugly and easier parseable I guess.

Comment: @FredOverflow But there was no backward compatibility requirement for references, yet C++ copied the pointer syntax. =(

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are correct about your distinction,

There's C++ [code](http://google.com/codesearch#search/&q=%5E%5Cs%2a%5Cw+%5Cs%5C%2a%5Cw%20file%3acxx&type=cs) in the `T *` style.

There's C [code](http://google.com/codesearch#search/&q=%5E%5Cs%2a%5Cw+%5C%2a%20file%3ac&type=cs) in the `T*` style.

I think it's just a matter of personal preference of the project participants.

Comment: I explicitly wrote "most" instead of "all". Also, I can only say this for code I have seen so far, obviously. :P

Comment: Yes, but if you'll look at the amount of code, not written in this style you might conclude that `most` might be your personal impression, and not a fact.

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw some controversy into the matter:

- C++ users commonly state that one declaration per line makes it okay to put the asterisk on the type (the left). `int* a; int* b;`
- Both C and C++ are parsed with the asterisk attached to the name (on the right). `int *a;`
- C++ preprocessors often move the asterisk to the left. C preprocessors move it to the right.
- In either language, putting it on the left will look weird for declaring multiple variables of the same type in the same statement. `int* a, * b, * c;`
- There are some syntactic elements that look stupid with it on the left. `int* (* func)()`.

There are other elements of C that are incorrectly used, such as `const`, which belongs on the right too! `int const a;`. This is commonly put on the left of the type, despite belonging to the type *to its left*. Many compilers have to be modified to handle this usage. In C++ you can observe this is conformed to with constant methods, as the compiler can't deduce for you if it's put on the left: `int A::a() const`. This also breaks down with nested usage of `const`, `restricted` and friends with such declarations as `int const *`. Conventional usage of `const` would suggest this is a constant pointer to an integer, but that's actually `int *const`.

### tl;dr

You've all been doing it wrong all along, put everything on the right.

Comment: "`int const *`. Conventional usage would suggest this is a constant pointer to an integer" What nonsense. It looks nothing like English or any other human language, so without foreknowledge of what this declaration means, why would you assume that it's a constant pointer to an integer? The correct, RTL reading is just as logical.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I think we're arguing the same thing here. Except that by conventional usage I meant _C usage_, not English.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Just a FYI, I don't know if C is actually RTL, but the spiral rule has unequivocable traction: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Answer (score 1):

C declarations follow the same rules (eg precedence) as expressions. In fact, it's perfectly valid to consider a declaration like

```
int *foo;
```

as declaring the type of the expression `*foo` (ie the indirection operator applied to `foo`) as `int` instead of `foo` as being of type `int*`.

However - as other already pointed out - in C++ its common to think of types as a seperate, and - due to templates - modifyable entity, and thus it makes sense to use a declaration like

```
int* foo;
```