# Declaring multiple variables in C++ , is attributes declared for all those variables?

Tags: c++, variables

If i define three objects like the following:

```
const string & textA = messages.at(0), 
               textB = messages.at(1), 
               textC = messages.at(2);
```

Are `textB` and `textC` actually a reference?
Do I have to place the `&` in front of both `textB` and `textC`?

Thanks!

Comment: The & is needed in front of every variable. (The same is true for pointers.)

Comment: Also, beware of this if the `at()` method returns a *value* (as opposed to a reference). There's nowhere for the value to be stored after this declaration takes a reference to it, so the temporary will be immediately destructed.

Comment: @GregHewgill oh, didn't see the word _if_, sorry

Comment: @GregHewgill: That's not true. If you use an assignment to a `const &` to give a temporary a name, that temporary is guaranteed to stick around until the name goes out of scope.

Comment: @warl0ck: The best plan really is to not have multiple declarations in the same statement. Less confusion all around that way.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I wasn't aware of that feature. Can you give a reference (no pun intended!) for that?

Comment: @GregHewgill: I don't know which section of the standard talks about it, but the bottom of this page contains another (ahem) reference to the idea: http://www.xgc.com/manuals/gcc-erc32-ug/p2node78.html - and here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760578/const-reference-to-temporary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`textB` and `textC` are not references.  Think of the `&` as if it belongs with the variable, not the type.

(Just checked with g++)

Comment: This is why old timers seem to prefer declaring pointers as `int *x;` instead of `int* x;`

Comment: @Adam: I hope that doesn't make me an "old timer"... at least I don't feel like one! Why would anybody prefer it the other way, given the way declarations work?

Comment: @Greg: There are many discussions on that on SO, I for one put the emphasis on types, with `int&` being the type. Related: [Why is it thought of `T *name` to be the C way and `T* name` to be the C++ way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449997/why-is-it-thought-of-t-name-to-be-the-c-way-and-t-name-to-be-the-c-way)

Comment: @GregHewgill, s/old timer/wise/ ;) I think most people consider the * or & to be part of the type, so it's natural to group it with the rest of the type. 15 years of C and I still think that way, and I feel the way declarations work is unintuitive.

Comment: @Xeo: That discussion still amuses me. It's trivial, but the `int* var;` style annoys me.

Comment: @Omni: Glad we didn't have to work on the same project yet. ;)

Answer (score 2):

use this notation instead and you will see what happens:

```
const string     &textA = .., // reference
                 &textB = .., // reference
                 textC = ..; // value
```

Same thing applies to pointers:

```
const string     *textA = .., // pointer
                 *textB = .., // pointer
                 textC = .. ;// value
```

Combined

```
const string     *textA = .., // pointer
                 &textB = .., // reference
                 textC = .. ;// value
```