# Why is return type before the function name?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-design, return-type, function-signature

The new C++11 standard adds a new function declaration syntax with a trailing return type:

```
// Usual declaration
int foo();

// New declaration
auto foo() -> int;
```

This syntax has the advantage of letting the return type be deduced, as in:

```
template<class T, class U>
auto bar(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u);
```

But then **why the return type was put before the function name in the first place?** I imagine that one answer will be that there was no need for such type deduction in that time. If so, is there a reason for a hypothetical new programming language to not use trailing return type by default?

Comment: C++ really doesn't look like C++ anymore... =(

Comment: @paddy: It's pretty much C+++ now

Comment: @Mehrdad: Right. If you rotate the second `1`, `C+++` is what you get.

Comment: "there was no need for such type deduction in that time" - Indeed. The original version of C (and the primeval languages that inspired it) barely had types, let alone type deduction.

Comment: "use trailing return type by default" - there is no default. To write a declaration, you must choose one style or the other. If you mean, "could a hypothetical new language only use trailing return types", then of course it could; but C++ couldn't without breaking compatibility with all existing code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As always, K&R are the "bad guys" here. They devised that function syntax for C, and C++ basically inherited it as-is.

Wild guessing here:
In C, the declaration should hint at the usage, i.e., how to get the value out of something. This is reflected in:

- simple values: `int i;`, `int` is accessed by writing `i`
- pointers: `int *p;`, `int` is accessed by writing `*p`
- arrays: `int a[n];`, `int` is accessed by writing `a[n]`
- functions: `int f();`, `int` is accessed by writing `f()`

So, the whole choice depended on the "simple values" case. And as @JerryCoffin already noted, the reason we got `type name` instead of `name : type` is probably buried in the ancient history of programming languages. I guess K&R took `type name` as it's easier to put the emphasis on usage and still have pointers etc. be types.

If they had chosen `name : type`, they would've either disjoined usage from declarations: `p : int*` or would've made pointers not be types anymore and instead be something like a decoration to the name: `*p : int`.

On a personal note: Imagine if they had chosen the latter and C++ inherited that - it simply wouldn't have worked, since C++ puts the emphasis on *types* instead of *usage*. [This is also the reason why `int* p` is said to be the "C++ way" and `int *p` to be the "C way".](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6449997/500104)

> If so, is there a reason for a hypothetical new programming language to not use trailing return type by default?

Is there a reason to not use deduction by default? ;) See, e.g. Python or Haskell (or any functional language for that matter, IIRC) - no return types explicitly specified. [There's also a movement to add this feature to C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3386.html), so sometime in the future you might see just `auto f(auto x){ return x + 42; }` or even [`[]f(x){ return x + 42; }`](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/11/having-it-all-pythy-syntax/).

Comment: Another way to read those bullet points: (1) `i` is an `int`... if we merely use it. (2) `p` is an `int`... if we dereference it. `a` is an `int`... if we index it. `f` is an `int`...  if we call it.

Answer (score 7):

C++ is based on C, which was based on B, which was based on BCPL which was based on CPL.

I suspect that if you were to trace the whole history, you'd probably end up at Fortran, which used declarations like `integer x` (as opposed to, for example, Pascal, which used declarations like: `var x : integer;`).

Likewise, for a function, Pascal used something like `function f(<args>) : integer;` Under the circumstances, it's probably safe to guess that (at least in this specific respect) Pascal's syntax probably would have fit a bit better with type deduction.

Comment: Seeing how Brian Kernighan [wrote about his dislikes with Pascal](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html), it seems clear why Pascal's syntax isn't used.

Comment: @JesseGood: Yes and no -- at least to my recollection (which doesn't seem to be contradicted by a quick glance over the paper) he doesn't mention `int x;` vs. `x:int` as something he dislikes about Pascal. At the same time, given how much Pascal seems to have been disliked in general, you're probably right that copying almost anything from it probably would have been unpopular.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Hopefully this is the case, and the C++11 standard is not responsible for his departure from this earthly realm.